# Is it possible to add apps to Google+ pages?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-pages

Is there a way to add Apps to Google+ pages a la Facebook? For example the common iframe tab facebook allows. If not, is there any similar functionality available or something in store announced by Google?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is not.

Google tries to do every feature it rolls out the right way from the start so all new features, especially those giving 3th party developers access to Google+ content, roll out relatively slow.